# Can I go to the Legacy BIOS on a Chromebook without having to unscrew?

Tags: linux, bios, chrome-book, hp

My particular model of Chromebook apparently does not have the traditional screw to allow booting, and I'm trying to install Gallium OS on it. I have a "Kip (HP Chromebook 14 G4)", and there is no specific install page on the Gallium website. I'm wondering if there's a way to allow the legacy booting (sorry if that's not what it's called) through the terminal or something I can do with the software. Otherwise, if there's another simple way of changing it by opening the Chromebook up, that'd help as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the guide here: https://www.howtogeek.com/210817/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-your-chromebook/
 there is a key combination that enables the developer mode (hence usb booting).

Warning: **Be aware that the developer mode wipes your data.**

See the picture: [image: Key combination for chrome OS]